# Can you identify this 90s TV show where some characters walked around supporting their protruding heads with sticks?

Tags: story-identification, tv

Some friends remember having seen something like this in Argentina during the 90s. After a lengthy Google search I found [this](https://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=192283) forum talk, but I'm afraid their powers seem to be insufficient, as the show wasn't identified.

The characters were described as having huge horn-like protrusion sticking out of their heads, needing some kind of support to sustain the weight while they walk. This was compared to a patient with an IV pole:

[image: Clip Art of person with an IV pole]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Some Googling later, and I think I've found it.
Is it by any chance *[The Adventures of Captain Buzz Cheeply in 'A Clean Getaway'](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1380728/)*?
[image: Shot of the aliens with giant heads suspended by sticks on wheels]

Comment: Out of curiosity, what Google search found it?

Comment: It was in fact, "head so large it is supported by a stick cartoon"

Comment: Especially with identification requests like this it tends to do the job, since it leads to other people describing it. The intermediate step here was an old and barely replied to Yahoo Answers thread.

Comment: The question is already answered, but I would like to chime in as an eye witness :) The cartoon in question and many other shorts were pilot episodes as a part of Cartoon Network's "What a Cartoon!" project, promoted as "World Premiere Toons". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/What_a_Cartoon!
(see number 10) Some of the popular cartoons that resulted from the same project include [Dexter's Lab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dexter%27s_Laboratory), Power Puff Girls, and Johnny Bravo. "The Adventures of Captain Buzz Cheeply" was one of my favorites that premiered at the time.
That said, I would have

Comment: Now that's some good research.

Comment: "Everybody wants prosthetic foreheads on their real heads."